# WPF Task on Touch device not back properly to UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, task, ui-thread

I have a WPF application with some background tasks to be done that works perfectly on my laptop but it is not working fine in a tablet with Windows 7.

You click the screen, a loading image is shown while some background job is done, and at the end of the job a dialog with some info is shown. You press the button on the dialog and go back to the main screen.

In the tablet at the end when the dialog is shown you have to press the screen once to have the GUI "active" and then again to the application detect the click. Is like the ui thread gets "disabled" after the background task and needs the screen to be touch to be active again. It is quite annoying because the user has to press multiple times the button to get the action performed. This behaviour happens only in the tablet, not on a laptop...

Here is the code:

```
public void processTouch(Point p)
{
  Task getPendingDocsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(GetPendingDocs, CancellationToken.None,     TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
  Task afterGetPentingDocsTask = getPendingDocsTask.ContinueWith(w => AfterGetPendingDocs(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());  
}

private void GetPendingDocs()
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);            
}

private void AfterGetPendingDocs()
{            
     mainprogresscircle.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
     this.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#013857");
     WindowDialog aDialog = new WindowDialog(this);
     aDialog.ShowDialog();           
}
```

In the dialog the function when click is:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
   this.Close();          
}
```

And the XAML of the button on the dialog

```
<s:SurfaceButton                          
                    Margin="-4"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0"                                
                    Width="200"
                    Height="75"                        
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                    
                    Name="OpenButton" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Tahoma"
                    FontSize="20"
                    Content="Aceptar" 
                    Background="#78B41E" 
                    Foreground="White"
                    Click="Button_Click"  
                    IsManipulationEnabled="True"
                    />
```

I have tried also with BackgroundWorker and dispatcher and the behaviour is the same. Works perfectly on a regular computer but it does not response fine on a windows 7 touch device.

Any clue will be really wellcomed.

Thanks in advance,
Ivan.